# Cannot establish SSL connection with FTP using certfile (python)

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I'm trying to establish a connection with a FTP server using ftplib.
I received two files, a certificate with .crt extension and a certificate in PEM format (RSA KEY + Certificate).

I'm using the certificate in PEM format to create a context using the following code:

```
import ssl
from ftplib import FTP_TLS

ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
ssl_context.load_cert_chain('./certificate3') 
ftps = FTP_TLS(context = ssl_context)
ftps.connect(host, porta)
ftps.login(user = user, passwd = pwd)
ftps.prot_p()
ftps.nlst()
```

If I remove the last command (`nlst`) I receive the response: '230 Logged on'.
Therefore when I try to extract list of documents inside the FTP with `nlst()` command I receive an error message:

```
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected component did not respond
correctly after a period of time or the established connection has failed
because the connected host did not respond
```

Does anybody know what is wrong and how to fix the code in order to establish the connection?

Comment: Can you ist the directory contents with enabled SSL using any GUI/commandline FTP client running on the same machine as your Python code?

Answer (score 0):

I could establish connection to FTP server with WinSCP.
Through WinSCP I can run an script to synchronize the server with my local directory. Below you can find the command:

```
option batch abort
option confirm off
open ftp://user:password@hostserver:port -hostkey="SHA256 KEY"
synchronize local local_path remote_path
exit
```

This command must be in .txt file, and through a .bat file this command is executed.

Hope I can help other with the same issue.

Comment: This WinSCP script does not use encryption/SSL (unless you have a stored site in WinSCP with enabled SSL with name `ftp://user:password@hostserver:port` – what seems implausible) + `-hostkey` has no effect with `ftp://` sessions.

Comment: I tried different ways to establish connection with SSL with no success. Unfortunately, nobody in the community answered my question. I identified this way (WINSCP) that worked for me and for this reason I answered my own question to share with community this alternative way. If you know how to establish using ftplib and SSL I appreciate if you can help me as well.

Comment: I do not think you have answered you own question. I believe you had problems with ftplib because of the SSL. If you have chosen to give up on security as a workaround, I'm quite sure that ftplib would work to without SSL. There's probably no reason to give up on SSL AND switch FTP client at the same time. Not that I mind that you chose my WinSCP :)

Comment: Once you don't mind, I'll keep using your winscp instead of ftplib =)